# Getting module mismatch error when running postman collection in newman

Tags: postman, newman

Getting below error when trying to run a postman collection from newman.
Node Version is - v4.4.2
NPM version is - 2.15.0 
Newman version is - 2.0.5

```
newman -c TPO_Regression.json
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
            throw e
            ^

    Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.
        at Error (native)
        at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at bindings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your Node version got updated, so you'll need to either rebuild your `node_modules`, or reinstall Newman.

Rebuild:

```
npm rebuild Newman
```

Reinstall:

```
npm uninstall -g newman
npm install -g newman
```